# Listview Adapter with array object parameters possible?

Tags: java, android

I am unclear about the specifics of Adapters for Listview in Android Studio.

I've seen many examples of them being used, but never the way I want to use them.

I am trying to fill up a Listview with parameters of objects of the same class in an array.

I have an Array of objects with 2 String parameters and 1 Localtime parameter.

So far I've only seen examples where every different value they given to the Adapter is part of a separate Array.

What I want to do, is give the adapter 3 different parameter of objects from the same Array.

Is this possible?

I would think it is possible, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView myListView;
    String[] items;
    String[] prices;
    String[] descriptions;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources res = getResources();
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        items = res.getStringArray(R.array.items);
        prices = res.getStringArray(R.array.prices);
        descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);

        ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, items, prices, 
        descriptions);
        myListView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
```

Here items, prices, and descriptions are declared as string arrays and are instantiated as 3 string arrays in resources. Later they are referenced in the Adapter class constructor.

Instead I would want them to point at not arrays but parameters of objects of the same class from a single array.

Alternatively if that is not possible I can just get the parameters of all the objects from the array and create a separate array for each, but I feel like that is unnecessary, and there must be a simple way to do it, but I just don't know how to do it.

**EDIT:
I have found a tutorial video on youtube called "Android Beginner Tutorial #8 - Custom ListView Adapter For Displaying Multiple Columns" that is pretty much exactly what I was looking for.**

Answer (score 0):

You should try use BaseAdapter for it.

```
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Object> list;
    private Context context;

    ListAdapter(ArrayList<Object> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return list.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return 0L;
        //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        return view;
    }
}
```

And call it into your Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ArrayList<Object> myList= new ArrayList<>();

        //here you can add elements of type Object to your ListAdapter

        //instantiate custom adapter
        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(myList, this);

        //handle listview and assign adapter
        ListView lView = findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap those arrays under a single model class say `Product`

```
class Product {

    private String item;
    private String description;
    private int price;

    public Product(String item, String description, int price)
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    } 

    //getter setter here

}
```

Then in your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView myListView;
    String[] items;
    String[] prices;
    String[] descriptions;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources res = getResources();
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        items = res.getStringArray(R.array.items);
        prices = res.getStringArray(R.array.prices);
        descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);

        ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0; i<item.lenght; i++)
             productList.add( new Product(items[i],descriptions[i],Integer.parseInt( prices[i] ) );


        ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, productList);
        myListView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
    }
  }
```

You'll need to extend `ArrayAdapter` for that whos `getView()` would something look like this

```
 class itemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product>
  {


    @Override
    public view getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
         View view = inflateLayout(layout xml here);

         Product product = getItem(position);

         TextView view = (TextView) view.findViewById(id here);
         TextView.setText(product.getItem());
         .
         .
         .
         .

         return view

    }


  }
```